# Is it there are too many to do or be done?

Tags: passive-voice

There are too many of them to count.

There are too many of them to be counted.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Either one works.

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent sentences. I would suggest the first sentence to be a short hand of the second one.